# detection of handwritten alphanumerics in natural images

Tags: android, ios, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect the class & location of handwritten alphanumerics in a given image,
after looking around I found that the best way to achieve that is using deep neural networks, is there is a way to achieve that using tensorflow? (I would like to come up with something fast as it will be used in a live detection app on Android & IOS). more importantly, what kind of dataset can I use for this? will EMNIST be good for that?

or can I use YOLOV2 but with Alphanumerics for that ? if that's possible can EMNIST be used?